# Using standard Confluence caches when developing a plugin

Tags: performance, caching, confluence

I am developing a plugin for Confluence (version 2.10). My plugin has some expensive process that would benefit a lot from caching. I have implemented a proof of concept with a simple HashMap as a cache. Now I need to put a real cache in place.

I'd like to integrate my caches with the standard Confluence caches, so they could be managed and monitored with the "Cache Statistics" page in the admin.

I tried looking through the Confluence documentation, but could not find any informations on using Confluence caches. Are they just not exposed to plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the documentation : http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+Caching+Architecture

It is pretty simple to get an instance of a Cache Manager from Confluence, and use it to create your own cache.